# JQUERY : Immediate element (not children) highlight not in another div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am repeating div using foreach in my application. Because of this I am facing problem on current element click function. When ever I am clicking on current div, I need to highlight one more div which is placed down side of target div(this not children div). So, problem is the same div highlighting in another div also which is repeating using foreach.

Please have a look and kindly help me.

Here is the sample link[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzugwz8u/)

click on "click 1" div , then you will get what is problem.`

```js
$(".prev").click(function(){
   
    $( ".prev ~ div" ).css( "border", "3px groove blue" );
});
```

```css
div, span {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #bfa;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  div#small {
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #fab;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="prev">click1</span>
<div>click 1 highlight</div>    
</div>

<div>
<span class="prev">click1</span>
<div>click 1 highlight</div>    
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ids must be unique in HTML. So use a class instead:

```
<div>
<span class="prev">span#prev</span>
<div>div sibling</div>    
</div>

<div>
<span class="prev">span#prev</span>
<div>div sibling</div>    
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".prev").click(function(){
    $(".prev").next().css("border", 'none');
    $( this).next().css( "border", "3px groove blue" );
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tzugwz8u/4/)

Comment: I need to remove action also can u help me to achieve that. When I am clicking on second div first div highlight should be remove.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the styles in CSS and add a class and target the sibling using `+`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").click(function() {
    $("span").removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked')
  });
});
```

```css
div,
span {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #bfa;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}
div#small {
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fab;
}
.clicked + div {
  border: 3px groove blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="prev">span#prev</span>
  <div>div sibling</div>
</div>

<div>
  <span id="prev">span#prev</span>
  <div>div sibling</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to remove action also can u help me to achieve that. When I am clicking on second div first div highlight should be remove.

Comment: @Rayudu All you need is to remove the class `clicked` from all spans before adding class to the clicked `span`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Rayudu Glad to help. If you are satisfied with the answer you can accept this answer or  the other answer